# Better performance for calculating file size

Tags: java

I have a function that is properly performing for returning the size of documents. If there is a single document then the size is set, else I do a sum of the size of all documents and I concatenate it with the letter 'o'. Having a large number of records the time of treatment for each document is cumulating.
Any possible suggestions on what I can do on the level of this part of a function to improve its performance and response time in Java 7 ? either on the query or the calculation of the size of the documents?

```
    ResultSet rs1 = null;
    String fsize = null;
    String name = null;
    int elemFILESIZE = 0;
    List<DBUtil.Field> fields = new ArrayList<>();
    fields.add(new DBUtil.Field("RECK", id));
    String sql = "SELECT SIZE,NAME from DOCS WHERE RECK=? AND CURRENT='true'";
    rs1 = db.execQueryPrepareStatement("DOCS", sql, fields);

    if (rs1.next()) {
        fsize = rs1.getString("SIZE");
        name = rs1.getString("NAME");

        elemFILESIZE = SqlTool.selectOneInteger(DB,
                "SELECT COUNT(*) from DOCS where CURRENT = 'true' and RECK =" + id);
        if (elemFILESIZE == 1) {
            element.setSIZE(fsize);
        } else {
            String elemFSize = null;
            int totalFileSize = Integer.parseInt(fsize.substring(0, fsize.length() - 1));
            while (rs1.next()) {
                String singleFileSize = rs1.getString("SIZE");
                totalFileSize += Integer.parseInt(singleFileSize.substring(0, singleFileSize.length() - 1));
            }
            elemFSize = String.valueOf(totalFileSize) + "o";
            element.setSIZE(elemFSize);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Java 7? Or is this a typo and you mean Java 17?

Comment: Why do you execute a second query? Shoudn't `rs1.hasNext()` return the necessary information? If I understand your code correctly `elemFILESIZE` will be 1 if and only if `rs1.hasNext()` is false at that point (ignoring the race condition that the two separate SQL queries create, unless your transaction is set to be reproducible).